# Correct database implementation of groups like Google's circles

Tags: mysql, database-design, inner-join, foreign-key-relationship, database-normalization

```
create table USERS (  
    PK_USER int not null auto_increment primary key,  
    EMAIL varchar(100) not null,  
    PASSWORD char(40) not null  
);  

create table CIRCLES (  
    PK_CIRCLE int not null auto_increment primary key,   
    CIRCLE varchar(45),  
    FK_CREATOR int,  
    foreign key(FK_CREADOR) references USERS(PK_USER)     
);  

create table MEMBERS (  
    FK_MEMBERS int,  
    FK_CIRCLES int,  
    foreign key(FK_MEMBER) references USERS(PK_USER),  
    foreign key(FK_CIRCLE) references CIRCLES(PK_CIRCLE)  
);
```

is correct to have this dual reference to `PK_USER`?
(for ref. USERS=USUARIOS, MEMBERS=MIEMBROS, CIRCLES=CIRCULOS, CREATOR=CREADOR)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it *per se*, but if `MIEMBROS.FK_MIEMBRO` is the same as the `CIRCULOS.FK_CREADOR` referenced by `MIEMBROS.FK_CIRCULO` then it would be a violation of [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: I agree with what eggyal has said. But still when the number of data increase we have to sometime use denormalization.

Comment: thanks i already make queries and work fine, e.g if i want to know list the member's email & circle, and i use 2 inner join, but i get stuck when i want to put in the same list the email of the creator, WHAT i have to do?                                                                   select EMAIL, CIRCLE, EMAIL as CREATOR from MEMBERS                       inner join USERS on PK_USER = FK_MEMBER                          inner join CIRCLES on PK_CIRCLE = FK_CIRCLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what I can «infer» they are playing two different roles :

1. In CIRCULOS you're tracking WHO did the provisioning of the entity
2. In MIEMBROS you're tracking the «membership» relation (a many-to-many relationship)

So: you're ok provided those were your intentions :)

Comment: alright, thanks for answer,  just using the members table and its references i can obtain  email(member),circle (the name of), but how should i do if i want a query with email(member),email(owner),circle??

Comment: You should write TWO queries within a SINGLE script. The first one will select the HEAD info related to the circle, the second one will retrieve the members. Consider that all database access libraries provide you a mean to get access to multiple recordsets. Another approach, if you like to layer your db access code using stored procedures, would be to code a SP that will return two OUTPUT parameters and a record set. Consider also that some DB access libraries provide sofisticated tools such as «hierarchical recordset».

Comment: The näive solution: 
SELECT C.CIRCLE, U_OWN.EMAIL AS OWNER_EMAIL, U_MEM.EMAIL AS MEMBER_EMAIL
FROM
    USERS U_OWN
    INNER JOIN CIRCLES C
        ON U_OWN.PK_USERS = C.FK_CREATOR
    CROSS JOIN USERS U_MEM
    INNER JOIN MEMBERS M
        ON U_MEM.PK_USER = M.FK_MEMBERS
WHERE
    C.PK_CIRCLE = @PK_CIRCLE
is often used as a «single-query» solution but I found it ugly, semantically not normalized, and not performant for very huge resultsets where a lot of data is replicated unnecessary. (query not tested)

Comment: THANKS A LOT! this work, just removed the where clause and return exactly what i want.